# How can you check for specific characters in a string?

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I run the program it always prints true. For example, if I enter AAJJ it will print true because is only checking if the first letter is true.
can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

```
squence_str = raw_input("Enter either A DNA, Protein or RNA sequence:")

def DnaCheck():

    for i in (squence_str):
        if string.upper(i) =="A":
            return True
        elif string.upper(i) == "T":
            return True
        elif string.upper(i) == "C":
            return True
        elif string.upper(i) == "G":
            return True
        else:
            return False

print "DNA ", DnaCheck()
```

Comment: It is happening because after checking the first letter, you are returning `true` or `false` and hence your function ends there only and doesn't check for the next letter. Adjust your code according to your needs and don't return it in every statement. Instead use a flag to check.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to check that *all* of the bases in the DNA sequence are valid.

```
def DnaCheck(sequence):
    dna = set('ACTG')
    return all(base.upper() in dna for base in sequence)
```

`all(...)` uses a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) to iterate over all the nucleotides in the given DNA sequence, converting each into UPPER case and checking if it is contained in the DNA set `{'A', 'C', 'T', 'G'}`. If *any* value is not in this set, the function immediately returns `False` without processing the remaining characters in `sequence`, otherwise the function returns `True` once all characters have been processed and each is in the set.

For example, the sequence "axctgACTGACT" would return `False` after only processing the first two characters in the sequence, as "x" converted to the uppercase "X" is not in the DNA set `{'A','C', 'T', 'G'}` and thus the remaining characters in the sequence don't need to be checked.

Answer (score 2):

I like @Alexander's answer, but for variety you could see if

```
def dna_check(sequence):
    return set(sequence.upper()).issubset("ACGT")
    # another possibility:
    # return set(sequence).issubset("ACGTacgt")
```

might be faster on long sequences, especially if the odds of being a legal sequence are good (ie most of the time you will have to iterate over the whole sequence anyway).

Comment: For longer sequences this could be beneficial. But the intended use case here is for a manually entered string, so it would probably be relatively short.

Comment: (shrug) if you are waiting on user input, any plausible function will be incredibly faster in comparison. I was thinking more in terms of "if you're going to start processing 20MB input files".

Answer (score 0):

More at the level of your current learning ...

You have the logic reversed.  You have to check *all* the positions.  If any *one* of them fails to identify as a nucleotide in "ACTG", then you immediately return **False** for the string.  Only when you've passed *all* of the characters, can you confidently return **True**.

```
import string

def DnaCheck(squence_str):

    for i in (squence_str):
        if string.upper(i) not in "ACTG":
            return False

    return True

test_cases = ["", "AAJJ", "ACTG", "AACTGTCAA", "AACTGTCAX"]
for strand in test_cases:
    print strand, DnaCheck(strand)
```

Output:

```
 True
AAJJ False
ACTG True
AACTGTCAA True
AACTGTCAX False
```

Comment: Using `all` will immediately short circuit if you have one failure.  Not sure how pythonic the `for` loop is here. Unless you then go on to say that the pythonic way to accomplish this for-loop is by using `all`.

Comment: I suspect that **all** is about two steps beyond OP's current level of academic comfort.  This **for** loop also exits at the first failure.  **all** is certainly more Pythonic, but this solution has a better chance of illustrating the error in the posted code.

Answer (score 0):

[Check out this picture to see how this function works!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOYwR.png)

```
def DnaCheck(sequence):
    for base in sequence:
        if base.upper() in ('A', 'C', 'G', 'T'):
            continue
        else:
            print('False')
            return
    print('True')
```

As shown in the image above, we start with iterating through each base in a given sequence using a `for` loop. `if` a given base belongs to ('A', 'C', 'G', 'T') set (green signal), function will `continue` to the next base and check that (go back to beginning of `for` loop, without running the subsequent code). It will `continue` to check the subsequent bases unless it meets a base which doesn't meet criteria (red signal), at which point `else` statement will be executed to print 'False' and function will terminate using `return` (`print('True')` will not be executed). In case of valid sequence, after checking the last base, `for` loop will end and `print('True')` will be executed.